# Using sed to replace special characters

Tags: sed

This works to replace `tom` with `sam` in a file:

```
sed 's/tom/sam/g' file_1 > file_2
```

But this does not:

```
sed 's/*****/sam/g' file_1 > file_2
```

To replace the special characters `*****` with the word `sam`. I have tried with a slash `\*` but errors.

Comment: What command did you try with `\*` and what the errors you got?

Comment: i have tried : sed 's/****/sam/g' test.txt > test2.txt and results in error :sed: bad regex '*****': Invalid preceding regular expression - this does have the blackslash \before the *

Comment: You may try to escape every special character: `sed 's/\*\*\*\*\*/sam/g'`

Answer (score 24):

You need to escape the special characters with a backslash `\` in front of the special character, e.g.:

`sed 's/\*/t/g' test.txt > test2.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the special characters with a backslash `\` in front of the special character. For your case, escape every special character with backslash `\`.

eg: `**** boy is ****`

```
sed 's/\*\*\*\*/sam/g' filename
```

ans :

```
sam boy is sam
```