# Sed - Find and Replace "..\" with "..\..\" - AKA Down 2 Levels

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace `..\` with `..\..\`.

(I moved a folder and need to manipulate file paths in an xml.)

I finally got my command to go without errors, but didn't get the result I wanted, can anybody tell me whats wrong?

Here is what I tried `sed -i -e 's|..\\|..\\..\\|g' file.xml`

Comment: `.` is a match any char, needs to be escaped.

Comment: Don't use `-i` until after you are sure you are going to get the correct result.

Comment: I more of an Try and Fail and restore backup and try again kinda guy :P @NickD

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e 's|\.\.\\|\.\.\\.\.\\|g'
```

[Using sed to replace special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212925/using-sed-to-replace-special-characters)

I didn't realize I had to escape `.`